# text to 2D array on Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to read a text file and send the info to 2D array, but after loading the array, it reads all zeroes. What can I do to stop the Arduino from doing this and get the array with my required data?

```c
/* This program was created by ScottC on 8/5/2012 to receive serial signals from a computer to turn on/off 1-9 LEDs */

int** ptr;

void setup() {
  // initialize the digital pins as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  // Turn the Serial Protocol ON
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  byte byteRead;

  if (Serial.available()) {

    /* read the most recent byte */
    byteRead = Serial.read();
    //You have to subtract '0' from the read Byte to convert from text to a number.
    byteRead = byteRead - '0';
    ptr = new int* [byteRead];

    int i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < byteRead; i++) {
      ptr[i] = new int[3];
      for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (Serial.available()) {

            /* read the most recent byte */
            byteRead = Serial.read();
            //You have to subtract '0' from the read Byte to convert from text to a number.
            byteRead = byteRead - '0';
            ptr[i][j] = byteRead; 
            Serial.print(ptr[i][j]);
        }
      } 
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: I see nothing there at all to do with text files, and the whole program looks somewhat daft. Please take a step back from the program and think about what you want to achieve before dumping someone else's code on us.

Comment: For reading serial data on the Arduino you should really read this to clear up some of your bad misconceptions: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code but instead of correcting I recommend that you start by checking that your assumptions about the format is correct. Send your data to this "reduced" variant of your sketch. Does it work? Did you receive what you expected?

```
void setup() {
  // initialize the digital pins as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  // Turn the Serial Protocol ON
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  byte byteRead;

  if (Serial.available()) {

    /* read the most recent byte */
    byteRead = Serial.read();
    //You have to subtract '0' from the read Byte to convert from text to a number.
    byteRead = byteRead - '0';
    Serial.print(F("byteRead = "));
    Serial.println(byteRead);

    int i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < byteRead; i++) {
      for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (Serial.available()) {

            /* read the most recent byte */
            byteRead = Serial.read();
            //You have to subtract '0' from the read Byte to convert from text to a number.
            byteRead = byteRead - '0';
            Serial.print(i);
            Serial.print(':');
            Serial.print(j);
            Serial.print(F(":byteRead = "));
            Serial.println(byteRead);
        }
      } 
    } 
  }
}
```

Did you see the issue with:

```
    for ( i = 0; i < byteRead; i++) {
    ...
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: The worst part of that code is the bit that reads `for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (Serial.available()) {

            /* read the most recent byte */
            byteRead = Serial.read();`